# Stop Curl redirecting to new page

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to make curl request to domain: http://xyz.com. here is my code.

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $arrData);

    curl_exec($ch);
```

While making request it gets redirected to some page within and don't come back to my page.

How can i stop being redirected in middle of curl request.

M sorry guys...

after the suggestion i tried CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  to 0 and it worked... it was my mistake that i didn't remove next line of header redirection and it went on passing and passing...

sorry my mistake.

once more... CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to 0 wont transfer...

Comment: How do you know it redirects?

Comment: if CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION is 0, curl did not follow any redirect. period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to play with :

1. `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`,
2. `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`,
3. `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`,
4. `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`

And think to log, it's easier to debug with it !

```
$handle = fopen('log.tmp', 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $handle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` option.

**CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS** : The maximum amount of HTTP redirections to follow. Use this option alongside CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference if `FOLLOWLOCATION` is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think because that page checks your user-agent or sets cookies, so you need to try mimic web browser as much as possible.

Like adding user-agent:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_2) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.63 Safari/535.7');
```

Or try set cookie:

```
    $cookieJar = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieJar);
```

If you provide url maybe i could help more.

Comment: does cookiejar also works for other domain? sample url is ok or exact url is needed? coz the url is kept secret for somewhat reason...

Comment: with web browser you can open that web page without problems, right?